Obtaining OSM Way Measurements
I have just over 300 Way IDs and I want to retrieve the length of each way and the terminal nodes of each way (that is the nodes where the way starts and ends). On ID, I have to manually select the way and use the shortcut: Ctrl + Shift + M, to get measurement details including the length of the way as in the pic below:

How do I retrieve the length of the way and the terminal nodes for all 300 Way IDs I am working on without going through the manual process described above? Can this be done programmatically via Overpass Turbo, JOSM, or using the OSM API?
I've tried using overpass turbo to no success
